# MS SQL Linked Server Insert Error

Tags: sql-server, migration, linked-server, greenplum

As part of data migration, I have created linked server for Greenplum database in MS SQL 2019. I am able to query using linked server. Select & insert commands are working fine for most of the tables.

While doing querying for one column which is
having data as ""1111-1111-1111.zip;zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-1111.zip;" format and
data type as character varying (varchar) and
max length less than 8000 characters in GPDB,
Getting below error.

> OLE DB Provided "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServer" returned
> message "Requested conversion is not supported". cannot get the
> current row value of column "[MSDASQL].column" from OLE DB provider
> "MSDASQL" for linked server.

Greenplum using UTF8 encoding & MS SQL using `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

Manual insert command in MS SQL with the same data is working fine in SSMS.
I tried insert statement using cast still fails. Select query with collate (`Latin1_General_CI_AS`) also fails with same error.

Comment: Does any of the information in this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10122693/5059085) help?

Comment: Thank you @J.D. for sharing the post. As text data type is going to deprecated, haven't tried. Now created table on both DB with text data type, linked server conversion (insert & select) works fine. Post that altered the data type on both DB.